# IOTA Whitepaper: What is z in Section 4.1?

Tags: iota-network, white-paper

Everything in the equation is defined except z.  Is it supposed to be another parameter that is chosen like alpha?  I want to actually use some reasonable sample variables and test this.

[image: what is z]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable `z` is just the index over which the sum in equation (13) iterates. This is similar to when you have

```
 \sum_{i=1}^n ...
```

where `i` is the standard index (so no need to "define" `i` separately).

Now, notation `z:z⇝x` simply means `All z such that z approves x` or `All z such that z⇝x`. So we sum over all transactions `z` that directly approve our transaction `x`. Note that `y` is one of these `z`.